# How do I inherit KDoc documentation in Java class?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, javadoc, kdoc

I have Kotlin classes with KDoc, for example:

```
abstract class Something {
  /** # Documentation */
  abstract fun someFun()
}
```

This class is extended by Kotlin and Java classes. KDoc is correctly inherited by Kotlin classes. KDoc is shown upon clicking Ctrl+Q in Intellij in the subclass. However, it does not work if the subclass is written in Java. KDoc is not inherited in this case.

How can I inherit the KDoc in Java?

Comment: The linked question is pure Kotlin, this one is about Java. Not a duplicate, I think.

Comment: Can you provide sample code of how you are trying to extend this in java?

Comment: ```class SomethingElse extends Something { /* methods overrides here */ }```

Comment: By inherit do you mean you want to see the comment when pressing Ctrl + Q or do you want the entire comment to be copied over? I think the entire comment cannot be copied as Kdoc differs from Javadoc